# What does constraining a generic parameter by a lifetime (T: 'a) mean?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I understand why a reference passed to a function must come with minimal required lifetime: to be sure that object behind is not destroyed while function is still operating. What puzzles me is the following:

```
fn a_function<'a, 'b, T>(arg: &'b T)
where
    T: 'a,
{
    // ...
}
```

The only reference that comes into the function has the lifetime `'b`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's already been answered but I cannot put my hand on it.

Comment: The question, which you have deleted, would be: what does exactly "T: 'a" mean?

Comment: From the linked duplicate: *What `T: 'a` is saying is that any references in `T` must outlive `'a`.*.

Comment: @user3284063 not *deleted* — moved the the questions title; where it belongs.

Comment: And the answer to the implicit question about this particular function is that *this specific bound* is apparently meaningless.

Comment: I disagree with the premise that "a reference [...] must come with minimal required lifetime *to be sure that object behind is not destroyed while function is still operating*". References come with lifetimes so the *caller* can be sure that the called function doesn't do something that would be illegal *for the caller to do* (e.g., storing a short-lived reference into a long-lived data structure, as in the first linked duplicate).